# Needed explanation for the return type of angular method

Tags: angular

I have the following method on Angular 8 application. This method basically returns the httpHeaders. What I didn't understand is the return type. Especially the | notation. What I understand | is used when using pipes. So could somebody explain what is the meaning this entire statement

```
{ headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } }
```

Method

```
 protected getRequestHeaders(): { headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } } {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': `application/json, text/plain, */*`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,DELETE,OPTIONS'
        });

        return { headers: headers };
    }
```

Comment: `|` is used for pipes when used in an Angular expression inside an Angular component template. It doesn't have the same meaning in a completely different context, i.e. types in TypeScript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types.

Comment: I have gone through the link and just understood the use of | in a simple context but still not clear on the above statement used in the code. Could somebody explain that in detail please

Comment: What can't we just use return type to be  headers: HttpHeaders only?

Comment: You should, since the method only ever returns that. Whoever chose this type as the return value didn't understand what they was doing, or planned to return something else later.

Answer (score 0):

`|` notation in Angular HTML template and `|` notation in typescript both have different meaning.

For HTML template, as stated by you, `|` is used for `pipes`.

As the typescript goes,

```
{ headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } }
```

Above syntax means, return type of method can have different types (`or`),

1. `headers: HttpHeaders`
2. `[header: string]: string | string[]`

Also as second type goes, the value may be a string or an array of strings, but there's always a string key.

1. `[header: string]: string`
2. `string[]`

Comment: I'd add that the second union type means that the value may be a string a or an array of strings, but there's always a string key.

Comment: As @JB Nizet as said above the second type is not needed. I have tried to read the return type as what is explained by you but unable to understand the rationale behind it ?

Comment: Yes, Second type is not necessary, as your are returning type of `HttpHeaders`